# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Tags: xml

I get the above error when viewing a xml document. The problem seems to be the second ( = ) in the following link.

> http://mysite.com/viewpage.php?u=1020&op=new

In the link & is replaced by & amp; without the space. 
Any help as to why this is throwing an error would be greatly appreciated.

This is how the link is added to the xml file structure

```
<item link="http://mysite.com/viewpage.php?u=1020& amp;op=new">
   <![CDATA[Some text and other stuff here]]>
</item>
```

Comment: Your link is broken, No page to display.

Comment: Give us more of the document.

Comment: Edited to include the item that is throwing the error. If I remove the link it works fine.

Comment: Does the space before `item` really exist? If so, it should be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the space does not exist but i had to include to display the code correctly when posting. For some reason the line disappears if I do not include the space.

Comment: That space also does not exist in the actual file.

Comment: What does the rest of the `item` element look like? Is it an empty element?

Comment: Edited with the full line, no space exist in the actual file.

Comment: @jcure: when posting code or XML, you need to highlight those lines in the editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) - then they'll be nicely formatted, and you don't need to mess around with your XML at all.....